# Digital logic design /circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, proteus

Can I further minimize this boolean expression

A'BC+AB'C+ ABC'

As I guess It can't be  further minimized

Comment: According to what criterion of optimization? There are lots of tools to help you answer this question, including things like berkley's espresso (https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/pubs/downloads/espresso/) and random online solvers (e.g. http://tma.main.jp/logic/logic.php?lang=en&type=eq&eq=%7EABC%2BA%7EBC%2B+AB%7EC)

Comment: You might also want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer which has a software section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boolean expression A'BC+AB'C+ ABC' corresponds to the following [K-Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image: K-Map of the Boolean Expression]

As you can see, there are no adjacent 1 values in the map, therefore the S.O.P expression above is in fact, the most minimized.

If you don't want to use a K-Map, or want to double check your answer, you can use sites like [these](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator).

Answer (score 2):

No, You cannot minimize this Boolean expression any more.
Also [this website](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/) could help.