# Digital logic design/Circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, proteus

Can I write this boolean equation

A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC

As
A xor B xor C
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer to your previous question help? [Digital logic design /circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535710/digital-logic-design-circuit). I know it's not exactly the same formula but it's clearly a question that can use the same procedure to establish what you ask.

Comment: No I'm just confirming is it right or wrong

Comment: The answer you got showed how to draw a k-map and also linked you to a site that would do the job for you. If you want to ask if what you have derived is correct, you need to show the method you got to your answer.

Comment: Can you plz provide the link for minimization of boolean equation so I could easily verify it instead of upload question here

Comment: Just write out the truth tables for both and compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this sort of thing has been answered many times.  However as a student I would like to try my hand at answering this and enhance my understanding as a result.

You could use a Karnaugh map in this case, or you could solve by hand.

First I will factor out A' and A:

```
A'(B'C+BC') + A (B'C'+BC)
```

Notice that the left side of the equation has a xor already (x'y+xy'= x xor y).

```
A'(B xor C) + A (B'C'+BC)
```

If you convert the far-right factor from AND-OR to OR-NAND with DeMorgan's theorem, you end up with:

```
A'(B xor C) + A ((B'C')'(BC)')'
A'(B xor C) + A ((B+C)+(B'+C'))'
```

Now if you factor everything inside of the NAND operation, a xor appears:

```
A'(B xor C) + A (BC'+B'C)'
A'(B xor C) + A (B xor C)'
```

Treating (B xor C) as a variable in the equation for xor, you can see that it is being xor'd with A:

```
(B xor C) = v

A'v + Av' = A xor v

A xor ( B xor C )
A xor B xor C
```

So, yes:

```
A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC = A xor B xor C
```